# Looping Work Flow with SharePoint designer 2010

Tags: workflow

I am developing a SharePoint Workflow with which if a user submit details then it needs to go to the team leader and if the team leader approves it will go to the director and if the director approves id then the work flow stops.

Now the problem is that if the team leader or director rejects it then it needs to go back to the user or team leader respectively and they have to make necessary correction and re start the process.

i have created a sequential work flow which will work one time which will not go to the step above or the if condition above the statement.

is there any way to loop the workflow ?

or is there any way when each time when an item is changed the workflow start from step 1 itself.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Have the workflow start when the ListItem changes.
Then, when the director (or someone else) does not approve, send a notification - and stop the workflow. When the people who received the notification make the required changes to the ListItem, the workflow starts again, and everybody needs to approve the ListItem again.
And since maybe i.e the team leader has approved the old version but not the changed version, it is a good idea that everybody needs to approve the ListItem again.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on [my blog post](http://vojtan.wordpress.com/2010/10/07/creating-loops-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflows/). It is a little bit tricky, but I successfuly implemented a workflow with loops this way.